# Rewrite url http://Root/Home to http://Root in MVC

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the url http://www.root.com/home to http://www.root.com in web.config. This is a MVC5 framework.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<rule name="Redirect"  enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$"/>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}"  pattern="^/home$"  />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.root.com" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```